# Sonarqube vs eslint rules (named function vs anonymous function)

Tags: node.js, sonarqube, anonymous, eslint

I've written this code for a mongoose schema:

```
localeTypesSchema.statics.findAndModify =
    function findAndModify(query, sort, update, options, callback) {
        const promised = q.nbind(this.collection.findAndModify, this.collection);
        return promised(query || {}, sort || [], update || {}, options, callback);
    };
```

SonarQube is complaining (major, code smell) about `Make this function anonymous by removing its name (cross-browser, user-experience)`.

If I remove the name then `eslint` extending `airbnb` complains (warning) about `[eslint] Missing function expression name. (func-names)`.

I can't transform it to an arrow function as it makes use of `this`, and `this` should be bind to function caller and not to scope of arrow function.

How should I write the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both choices can be valid: read the description of the [SonarQube rule](https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=javascript%3ANamedFunctionExpression) and of the [eslint rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/func-names). In fact, the eslint rule can be configured to enforce one choice or the opposite one. Tools are just here to help if you want to enforce one rule.

Comment: So is there a way that I can use all rules in `airbnb` eslint extension?

Comment: If you want function expressions to be named, you should disable the SonarQube rule.

Comment: I can not find the SonarQube role that should be disabled. Can you please help me?

Comment: @AndréFiedler Look for a rule named "NamedFunctionExpression" on your SonarQube server and remove it from your [quality profile](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Quality+Profiles).